# Can I load a SQLite column of binary data into switches?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have SQLite Database. I've set it up using android and listview such that I can view the data in the database. Most of the columns are text. For these, I have set up several textView objects that permit me to upload the text in the SQL columns into the list view.

But I have a column of binary data. And I'd like to load this such that if there is a "0" in the column, then the switch is in the off position, and if there is a "1" in the column, the switch is in the on position?

Do I need to set up some kind of case system on the switch object?

Here's my current code for populating the ListView

```
    // THIS UPDATES THE LIST
    private void populateListViewFromDNewBMetric(){
        Cursor cursor = mydbmetric.getAllRows();

        // Setup mapping from cursor to view fields
        String[] fromFieldNames = new String[]
                {DBAdapter_Metrics.KEY_ROWID,DBAdapter_Metrics.KEY_NAME,DBAdapter_Metrics.KEY_DESCRIPTION,DBAdapter_Metrics.KEY_SWITCH};
        int[] toViewIDs = new int[]
                {R.id.textViewMetricID,R.id.textViewName,R.id.textViewDescription,R.id.switch1};
        SimpleCursorAdapter myCursorAdapter;
        myCursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(),R.layout.item_metric,cursor,fromFieldNames,toViewIDs,0);
        ListView mylist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewMetric);
        mylist.setAdapter(myCursorAdapter);
    }
}
```

`DBAdapter_Metrics.KEY_SWITCH` and `R.id.switch1` are the things I don't think makes sense. It works for the other ones like `DBAdapter_Metrics.KEY_DESCRIPTION` because these are text. But `KEY_SWITCH` is an integer while  `switch1` is a switch not a field, so I'm not sure if I can somehow "load" a switch.

Comment: you need to setup a `ViewBinder` to your adapter

Comment: @pskink For what specific purpose?

Comment: to bind your data to a view that is not supported by a `SCA`, docs say: `"""An easy adapter to map columns from a cursor to TextViews or ImageViews defined in an XML file."""`